# Why does JQuery $.post submit twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, controller

Why does this call my Action twice?  For background, using .change only works when a user clicks somewhere else on the form.  Also .change will not fire when the browser is closed.  Hence the timer combined with the data-dirty property check.  Thanks in advance.

```js
var timeoutId;
$(function() {
  var formElements = $('#myformid').find('input, select, textarea').add('[form=myformid]').not(':disabled').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-dirty', false).on('input propertychange change', function() {
      var changedText = $(this).val();
      var commentID = $(this).attr('id');
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change
        // Saving to DB Here
        $.post('@Url.Action("UpdateComment", "CommentJournal")', {
          "ChangedText": changedText,
          "commentID": commentID
        });
        $(this).attr('data-dirty', true);
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

```cs
//Controller
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult UpdateComment(string changedText, string commentID) {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I hope someone is not a slow type or it will submit on them. :)

Comment: @epascarello scripts these days. Can't even stop to scratch anymore... as per your question, TerryH, `change` is included in `input`, besides other internal events depending on input element type and input method and/or device.

Answer (score 4):

Probably because both `input` and `change` events are being fired, with the `change` firing more than 1000ms after `input` fired, since `change` only fires when focus leaves the control. Example:

```js
var timerId = 0;
$("#field1").on("input change", function(event) {
  var type = event.type;
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("timeout fired for '" + type + "'");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<p>Type something in the first field, wait at least a second, then tab out of the field:</p>
<div>
  <label>
    First field:
    <input type="text" id="field1">
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    second field:
    <input type="text" id="field2">
  </label>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you hook `input`, there's no need to hook `change`.

Comment: TJ Well done.  Here is what I changed for others that find this problem.    //.on('input propertychange change', function () { Removed this
                                    .on('input propertychange', function () { //Replaced with this